# Running app crashes iPhone5S and forces hard reset with the error "failed to get task for process" on the second launch only

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have been at this for hours and am about to start flipping tables. This problem cropped up out of nowhere after working on this app successfully for about a month. No changes to build settings or build schemes or anything that I can think of.

If I build and run the app on an iPhone 4 I have no problems at all. If I build and run the app on an iPhone5S it will:

**On the first attempt**: Build successfully, appear to install the app on the device and launch it, but then fail with "error: failed to launch '.../MyApp.app' -- NotFound".

**On the second attempt**: Build, run, have a happy little debug session and everything is perfectly fine and dandy.

**On the third attempt**: Build successfully, begin to launch the app, and then will fail with "error: failed to launch '.../MyApp.app' -- Failed to get task for process -1". The phone will then become unresponsive, and the only way to bring it back is a hard reset.

Once or twice throughout the past few weeks I've had this problem happen, but after resetting everything was fine. Turning on or off building for arm64 doesn't seem to make a difference, and I can't think of anything else that would be different between the two devices.

Even a hint would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I changed the build scheme to "Wait for app to be launched manually", and by launching it myself after it's been built it seems to avoid the crashing. Obviously this doesn't fix whatever the underlying problem is, but at least I can function now.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this - it began after I upgraded to OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known bug, and it's resolved in Xcode 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this very same issue but the workaround I've found is to disconnect and reconnect the phone before running the app. Using this workaround, I haven't experienced the error as frequently as otherwise, but it's still a rather tedious process...

Comment: Tried that too. It makes the problem less frequent for me, but it does still happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known back to first Xcode 5 Previews. It helps to disconnect and connect the phone again. MY worst experience was Preview 4 with iPad. It till happens occasionally, but very rare compared to before.